# Cannot open my magento page after changing the base url in the admin panel

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin, magento2

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rfc0.png)

In the above screenshot i have changed the secure **base url form** http://localhost/magento/ to only magento. From then on i am not able to access any of my pages nor the admin panel.
I have also tried changing the it back to http://localhost/magento/ in my database table core_config_data. I didn't find any difference.

Comment: What error are you actually seeing? Have you added a hosts file entry or solved DNS some other way? And are you using https urls and have setup your web server to listen on 443 as well?

Comment: i am on localhost using xampp and when i try to open the web page the browser says the page was not found.